# Yii using making API call & request->getRawBody

Tags: yii

I know that instead of using `file_get_contents` in Yii you can somehow use `Yii::app()->request->getRawBody()` but where do you specify the url you are making the call to?

Comment: https://scrutinizer-ci.com/g/yiisoft/yii2/code-structure/master/operation/yii%5Cweb%5CRequest%3A%3AgetRawBody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent. You only use `CHttpRequest::getRawBody()` to retrieve the content of the request payload of the CURRENT request.

Below is the getRawBody implementation:

```
public function getRawBody()
{
    static $rawBody;
    if($rawBody===null)
        $rawBody=file_get_contents('php://input');
    return $rawBody;
}
```

To answer your question, the url is `php://input`